# How would I go about divorcing my spouse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was wondering how I would divorce my spouse before I get married. and could I get married again afterwards?

Comment: What do you mean by "divorce... before I get married".  If you're not married, how could you get a divorce?

Comment: tell you two went to climb a mountain and she never returned.

Answer (score 14):

I think most of the other answers (or comments) here say pretty much the same thing I've read and heard here and in other places:

**In Skyrim, marriage is forever.**

That means there is no divorce, and death does not end a marriage either.  You can never leave your spouse for another, or re-marry after being widowed.

That said, I believe the question here is a bit mis-phrased.  By specifying "before I get married", I think the asker is actually looking for how to call off the wedding.

This can effectively be done by simply not showing up at the temple, at the appointed time.  Then, go back to your betrothed and tell them you're no longer interested.  After this point, you should be able to choose another partner.

Alternately, you can call off the marriage during the ceremony itself as well.

However, the previous statement still stands - once you've said your "I do"s, it's a done deal forever.  (Or, until you reload to a previous save.)

If you're playing on PC, you can use the Console to reset the quest and remarry. [Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Marriage#Console_Cheats)

- Remove any Amulets of Mara from your inventory
- Enter the following into the console: `setstage RelationshipMarriage 10`
- Purchase an Amulet of Mara from Maramal, and complete the quest as usual—wear the amulet, find a spouse, agree to marry, and have a wedding.

Comment: The instructions you link also say `setstatge`, but further down it says `setstage` without that extra T.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to "divorce" your spouse, although the more accurate term might be "dispose" of them.

If you decide that you no longer would like to be with your current spouse, in your own home that you two share, sneak and become hidden, then silently kill your spouse. Store them in the basement, or somewhere so that no one will find her.

After this is done, go to the priest and receive another amulet. From there, you should be able to pursue another NPC.

Some players are talking about a bug that may occur, but I guess it just depends on how much you want it. Just to keep it on the safe side, save a file before you go about your job.

Comment: This game is messed up.

Comment: You Horrible Person

Comment: This is an amazing answer.

Answer (score 3):

The only way is for them to die. For some spouses you will need to complete certain quest lines before they become mortal.

Comment: Can you kill them and re-marry?

Comment: I suppose you could if you used a summon corpse spell, but I'm unsure if the people of Skyrim are cool with necrophilia.

Comment: Presumably the question was, if I married and then killed Betty, could I marry Veronica later now that I'm "widowed".

Answer (score 1):

Only if you lead him/her out of town to somewhere secluded, kill them, and break the bond. But I have heard there will be a bug if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

The Skyrim wiki says if you kill your spouse a bug maaaay occur and even if you are wearing the Amulet of Mara, there is still a chance you may not be able to remarry. I'm about to attempt it myself.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen, there is no option for even asking anyone about divorce... Including in the Temple of Mara. However, if you have a spouse who leaves the domicile, if you can manage to kill them stealthily, then it is not marked against you by the people. (unsolved murder) As well, if you acquire a NEW Amulet of Mara, you may be able to find you spark interests in other towns where you were not known to be wed. This is the only thing I have found to be a viable option.