# Is there a way to get a divorce in Skyrim? and if so can you remarry?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I go about divorcing my spouse?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35761/how-would-i-go-about-divorcing-my-spouse)

Hello I was wondering is there a way to divorce in Skyrim and if so, if I do this can I remarry?  And if this isn't possible if I brutally murder my wife can I remarry? You see there is a new person to whom I've fallen for, I don't think it right to go behind my wifes back.  Thank you!