# I can't get remarried in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok, so according to everything I've looked up you should be able to get married again after killing your spouse in Skyrim but I'm wearing the amulet of Mara and no one will give the dialogue options when I talk to them. Is this a glitch? Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [highest voted answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/47794/15184) marriage is forever and it is not possible to remarry after your spouse's death. According to answers on this [similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37120/can-you-remarry-if-your-spouse-is-dead), remarriage might not be possible due to a bug.

[UESP says the same thing](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage#Bugs) under the bugs section, unless you have the Unofficial Skyrim Patch. According to the [patch notes](https://www.afkmods.com/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Legendary%20Edition%20Patch%20Version%20History.html) for the Unofficial Patch this bug (Bug #14856) was patched by version 2.0.4.

> If a spouse is killed, it was intended that the player be allowed to
>   remarry but the command to restart RelationshipMarriage was never
>   added to RelationshipMarriageFIN. (Bug #14856)

Alternatively, if you have access to the console, you can try the console commands mentioned by [UESP for remarrying](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage#Notes). Or if mods are an option for you, you can try some of the [marriage mods](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/11235?tab=description) out there.

Answer (score 3):

You might try talking to maramall in Riften to see if he can help. I had to talk to him, like 3 to 4 times just to get it to work.